# Sql Server Join to Sub Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with call records and I'd like to get the number of calls in total and the total calls answered.

Here is what the table looks like:

```
 Extension | Status
 -----------------------
 300        Answered
 200        Not Answered
 ....       ...
```

What's the most efficient way to write a query that would return the extension, number of total calls (count on the entire table) and number of answered calls (count where `Status = 'Answered'`)?

I created a subquery and joined to it but it seems kind of inefficient so I have

```
    SELECT Extension, COUNT(*) AS total, answered.num as totalAnswered 
    FROM calls c INNER JOIN (SELECT Extension, COUNT(*) AS num FROM calls 
    WHERE Status = 'answered') answered ON c.Extension = answered.Extension
    GROUP BY Extension, answered.num
```

Thanks

Comment: A couple of details: 1) The query you posted is not valid. Consider fixing it. 2) Your query seems to imply that you want the counts to be per extension, but in the text, you seem to want counts based on the entire table. Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a `case` statement inside the `count` aggregate function for the total answered calls, you can keep your query very simple with a `group by`.

```
select extension,
       count(*) as total,
       count(case when status = 'answered' then 'X' end) as totalAnswered
  from calls
 group by extension
```

I am assuming you are trying to return totals *per extension*.

**EDIT**

I have to admit that your post in its current form is not 100% clear about your intent.  The query you posted implies that you want the counts to be *per extension*.  If that's the case, then the above query will work great.

But in the text of your post you say:

> number of total calls (count on the entire table)

... which seems to imply something different: that you *don't* want the counts to *per extension*.

For completeness, here is the query you can use if you want the counts to be global to the entire table, instead of *per extension*:

```
select distinct extension,
                count(*) over () as total,
                count(case when status = 'answered' then 'X' end) over () as totalAnswered
  from calls
```

And, if for some reason, you need a combination of both kinds of counts, then you can use something like this:

```
  select extension,
         count(*) as totalPerExtension,
         count(case when status = 'answered' then 'X' end) as totalAnsweredPerExtension,
         totalGlobal,
         totalAnsweredGlobal
    from (select *,
                 count(*) over () as totalGlobal,
                 count(case when status = 'answered' then 'X' end) over () as totalAnsweredGlobal
            from calls) c
   group by extension, totalGlobal, totalAnsweredGlobal
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Extension
    , COUNT(*) OVER() AS total
    , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY C.Extension) AS totalAnswered
FROM dbo.calls AS C
WHERE C.Status = 'answered';
```

You can use windows functions to achieve that. Should work just fine.

Comment: I believe the total count needs to include the non-answered items too.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. If it's the case, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Extention, 
       COUNT(*) as total, 
       SUM(answered) OVER (PARTITION BY Extention) as answered
FROM (
   SELECT Extention,
          CASE WHEN Status = 'answered' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as answered
) T
```